Unable to Access Internet on NAT64 Network Shared via macOS
When enabling NAT64 to test IPv6 connectivity via Internet Sharing on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, smartphones can connect to the shared network but fail to access the internet. In contrast, other devices like laptops can access the internet after a few seconds (up to one or two minutes).
Additional details:

The internet connection comes from the Ethernet interface and is shared via the WiFi interface on the MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.
I’ve tried setting up the network with both no security and WPA2 Personal, but the result is the same.
Two Windows 11 laptops successfully connected to the network and gained internet access after a few seconds.
I tested with an iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 15.8.3) and two Android phones. All connected to the network but had no internet access, despite receiving an IPv6 address and DNS (2001:2:0:aab1::1), the same as the laptops. Manually changing the DNS to Google's IPv6 DNS (2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844) didn't solve the issue.

Why do smartphones fail to access the internet while laptops can, even though they are receiving an equivalent IPv6 configuration?
